# How to make spaced text .equal() to unspaced text

Tags: java, android

I am working on code that takes two inputs like the following:

```
 ,Air Condition,
, Air Condition,
```

This text is received from a JSON object and the commas are something that must be considered.

As can be seen, one has white space at the beginning and the other doesn't. How can I compare them using the `equals()`?

So far, I have used the following code to compare the two strings:

```
if (oldSelected.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(String.valueOf(fc.getText()))){
    fc.setChecked(true);
}
```

However, it doesn't do what I expect it to do.

How i can trim this space and get the desired results?

Comment: Debug both value on Runtime

Comment: Are those  comma's part of the strings?

Comment: split text using comma after that use trim method to remove extra space and compare the objects

Comment: "s t".replace(" ", "");

Comment: you can replace all space with nothing then check those, like: `",aircondition,".equalIgnoreCase(String.valueOf(fc.getText).replaceAll(" ","")))`

Comment: use yourStringVar.trim() to trim white spaces at the start and end of the string.

Comment: @RahulViswanath that's already worked with english words only, but didn't work with other languages /

Comment: Could you provide all the different use cases where it is failing?

Answer (score 1):

You need to trim the white spaces first.

```
String oldSelected = ",Air Conditioner,";
String newSelected = ", Air Conditioner, ";

if(oldSelected.replaceAll("\\s", "").equalsIgnoreCase(newSelected.replaceAll("\\s", ""))){
    // Do Something
}
else{ // Do Something Else
}
```

Hope that helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1 = ",Air Condition";
    String s2 = ", Air Condition";
    System.out.println(s1.equals(s2.replace(", ", ",")));
}
```

or, if you want to keep space between words, you may use like this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1 = ",Air Condition";
    String s2 = ", Air Condition";
    System.out.println(s2.split(", ")[1]);
    System.out.println(s1.split(",")[1]);
    System.out.println(s1.split(",")[1].equals(s2.split(", ")[1]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

`String.valueOf(fc.getText())).replaceAll("\\s+","")`

This removes all whitespaces and non-visible characters (e.g. tab, \n)

Answer (score 0):

you can use String methot called  SPLIT  for example  you  have

```
String STR1 = "Ahoj"
String STR2 = "Ahoj "

String x[] = STR1.split(" ");
String y[] = STR2.split(" ");
```

then use simple for loop to check all  words :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, worked solution as @Rahul suggest to use `.trim()` but this worked with english words only, so in order to equalize all language i trim the equalized text to as below :

```
String checkedVal = oldSelected.get(i);
        checkedVal = checkedVal.trim();
        if (checkedVal.equalsIgnoreCase(String.valueOf(fc.getText().toString().trim()))){

            fc.setChecked(true);
        }
```

Thanks for all answers.